# Kubectl unavailable after setting up proxy

Tags: kubernetes-helm, grafana, kubectl

I am trying to install grafana using Helm. Internet is not directly accessible therefore I use proxy server. However when proxy is set, kubectl goes unavailable.

Comment: what do you mean , kubectl goes unavailable ? what error,  :)

Comment: Hi, Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get https://nodelocal-api.xxxx.local:6443/version?timeout=32s: Forbidden

Comment: try doing `export NO_PROXY=nodelocal-api.xxxx.local:6443` and retry

Comment: Thanks, I tried above: 
echo $NO_PROXY
https://nodelocal-api.xxxx.local:6443

No difference
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get https://nodelocal-api.xxxx.local:6443/version?timeout=32s: Forbidden

Comment: Remove the port and try. Check out https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/530#issuecomment-318584208

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. However, I still couldnt install grafana. Error: failed to download "grafana/grafana" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help) I tried helm repo update 


helm repo update
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Unable to get an update from the "grafana" chart repository (https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts):
        Get https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts/index.yaml: dial tcp xxxx:xxx connect: connection timed out
Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: helm install grafana grafana/grafana --set ingress.enabled="true",ingress.hosts[0]='xxx.com' --namespace monitoring --set adminPassword='Rxxx'

Error: failed to download "grafana/grafana" (hint: running helm repo update may help) 


I tried "helm repo update" helm repo update Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories... ...Unable to get an update from the "grafana" chart repository (grafana.github.io/helm-charts): Get grafana.github.io/helm-charts/index.yaml: dial tcp xxxx:xxx connect: connection timed out Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈